# Google street view doesn't display in wordpress tabs

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display the Google map and street view with Wp Google Map WordPress plugin, in tabs. On first tab, I put the short code for map, which displays perfectly and in secondIi put the short code for street view, but I only see the gray background and controls, street view map doesn't display.

Here's my webpage http://pjvarquitetura.com.br/citycentrebooking/st_hotel/flat-110/

If you click on street view tab, it displays the controls, gray background and map will also be visible if you click on full screen option.

Any idea how to fix it?

I am using this plugin http://www.flippercode.com/product/wp-google-map-pro/ to display the maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The street view map is showing for me (on Chrome 45.0.2454.101). It just take some time to load.

Though if you look in the console you'll find the following error:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

If you look in your JS files you'll indeed find that you include twice the API:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://pjvarquitetura.com.br/citycentrebooking/wp-content/themes/citycenter-layout/js/gmap3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&#038;signed_in=true&#038;libraries=places'></script>
```

That's probably why it crash on some browsers.

Comment: The issue is if i put the street view in active tab, it works fine. But if i put it on 2nd tab (inactive) it doesn't display the map, only controls.

Comment: Did you tried to remove the second include of the gmap api as I told you?

Comment: Can't find, where it's included in theme. I include the footer codes in description., please take a look.

Comment: Don't edit my answer to add your code - edit your question instead. I looked at it and I don't think it's the _footer.php_ code, seems more like an other template file. Look both in _footer.php_ and _functions.php_, as the script can be included with `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: Great, it's fixed now. I just exclude that scripts from functions and it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad you solve it :)

Comment: Bro, it's not fixed completely. Sometimes it displays the street view and sometimes it doesn't. I am very confused..

Comment: It appeared perfectly in active tab, but doesn't work properly in inactive tab.

Comment: I tried it few times and don't see any issue in Chrome. Which browser do you use?